# connect gridgain server cache from memcache-binary client

Tags: node.js, memcached, gridgain

I have a gridgain running in remote server, i need to get data from gridgain using memcache-binary client. i'm able to connect to gridgain server but not able to connect to cache inside gridgain

```
var MemcachedBinary = require('memcached-binary');

var server = 'gridgain:port';

var params = { 
  use_buffers: false, // If true, always return Buffers instead of strings
  // defaults to false
};

var memcached_binary = new MemcachedBinary(server, params);

memcached_binary.get('DG', params, function(err, res) {
    if( err ) 
        console.error( err );
    console.log(res);
});
```

DG is one cache inside gridgain server

connection is getting closed(FIN) by gridgain when i do get, its not returning anything.

Comment: Can you provide the error message also?

Comment: is there a way to specifically connect to cachename and get data from tables inside cache in memcached-binary?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible to specify cache name for memcached protocol (using `default`). However, GridGain Professional 2.7.1 as well as Apache Ignite 2.7 should have native node.js client which will allow wide range of cache operations.